# How do I write the method name of a variadic method that also contains known arguments?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, arguments, variadic-functions

I'm trying to make a method which will accept an unknown number of arguments, and then a known number of other arguments. I'm just wondering about the syntax of naming the method. My method body seems fine.

I realize that I could make the method take the known arguments first and then the unknown arguments and it would look something like this:

```
-(id)init: (NSString*)type withModifier:(NSString*)mod withNames:(NSString*)names,...;
```

I'm looking to list the unknown arguments first, followed by the known arguments. How would I name a method like this?

This is what I'm trying to do, with proper syntax of course:

```
-(id)initWithNames: (NSString*)names,... withType:(NSString*)type withModifier:(NSString*)mod;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't - **the variadic argument must always be the last one.** Try

```
initWithType:(NSString *)t modifier:(NSString *)m names:(NSString *)n, ...
```

instead.